# Trying to produce JSON but importing the module is broken? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to parse a simple JSON string 
but the `import json` is not working. My code:

```
import json

d = {
    'first_name': 'Guido',
    'second_name': 'Rossum',
    'titles': ['BDFL', 'Developer'],
}


data_string = json.dumps(d)
print 'JSON:', data_string
```

Traceback error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json.py", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "/home/vmoni/workspace/json.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(json.dumps(d))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Comment: Do you have file named `json.py` (or package named `json`) in your working directory?

Comment: @Rogalski: look at the traceback. Yes.

Comment: Is there any file or folder as `json` ?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: yes, look at the traceback in the question. It's crystal clear, the file they run is named `json.py`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : You are right. I haven't noticed that.

Comment: I do note that your traceback and your actual code don't match. Where did the `print(json.dumps(d))` line come from? Your posted code uses a different `print` statement. I'd expect the exception to point to line 10, `data_string = json.dumps(d)`, instead (same `AttributeError`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your own script `json.py` and that's what is being imported:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json.py", line 1, in <module>
#      ^^^^^^^^^
    import json
  File "/home/vmoni/workspace/json.py", line 9, in <module>
#                  same file ^^^^^^^^
```

So your script imports `json`, which is really the same file, and that same module doesn't define `dumps`.

Rename your script (and make sure to delete the `json.pyc` file created next to it). You can't use the same name for your script as other top-level modules, not if you actually want those modules to be available.